# Importing .net users into firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

So to import into firebase, you need the hashing stuff to decode the password properly. We're using the microsoft owen security package from asp.net. I have a machineKey setup in the webconfig (I presume this is the hmac key I need to provide?)

```
<machineKey validationKey="<key>" decryptionKey="<decodeKey>" validation="HMACSHA256" />
```

and in the startup it's a simple

```
   public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {   
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),                
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),                
#if DEBUG
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
#endif
                Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()                
            };

            // Token Generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);            
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());


        }
```

To import into firebase, I'm using
(this is a dev DB user so it's ok that I'm showing the hash)

```
let userImportRecords = [
    {
        uid: 'afd698c4-4172-49f1-a6c4-77d175efbc1c',
        email: '<usersEmail>',     
        passwordHash: Buffer.from('APwDZFRV6tnEREBsmECj2LMkgUZAqfOAb9/u0nMra5WrHgVG0F7ggFQABt0Qdtsw3w=='),
        passwordSalt: Buffer.from('APwDZFRV6tnEREBs')
    }
];



var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./socket-server/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "<DB URL>"
});


admin.auth().importUsers(userImportRecords, {
    hash: {
        algorithm: 'PBKDF2_SHA256',
        rounds: 10000,
        saltSeparator: 16,
        // Must be provided in a byte buffer.
        key: Buffer.from('<webconfig machine decryptionKey key?>')
    }
});
```

This will import but the password doesn't work. I'm assuming there's something wrong with how I have the salt and/or the hash key. I didn't see in the asp.net documentation where it's setting the key, but I know I have that machineKey setup so I presume this is what it's using. (we have another server that validates the tokens itself)

I'm fairly certain the algorithm and rounds are correct (pulled from documentation). I know the salt is at the front of the password hash, I think it's 16 bytes. But in this setup, do I leave the 16 bytes included in the hash or do they need to be removed? Did I even remove the correct amount of characters or do I need to throw this string into memory and extract the 16 bytes manually. I feel like this is super close. I just need to re-arrange my values.

Comment: Pretty sure the SDK currently doesn't support password hashes where the salt appears first. See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/313. In the meantime try using the Firebase CLI.